# How to add smiley feature in Chat application in java?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

In my Chat application I need to add Smileys features ? How can I achieve this ?

we are using " Genesys " to create our Chat application ?

Is it possible to add Smileys ???

Please anyone can help me..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: i dont know any plug in or anything like that for it , but what i can suggest , before submitting your message check if it has any smiley representing code like " :) " then show a picture from your database replacing it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this [Pure CSS/JS Emoticons](http://os.alfajango.com/css-emoticons/)

or

you can replace the text with an image.

Check out the sample, the source and this **[jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Etmrs/)**

#### Sample

```
var emoticons = {
  smile: '<img src="path/smile.gif" />',
  sad: '<img src="path/sad.gif" />',
  wink: '<img src="path/wink.gif" />'
};

var patterns = {
  smile: /:-\)/gm,
  sad: /:-\(/gm,
  wink: /;-\)/gm
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p').each(function() {

  var $p = $(this);
  var html = $p.html();

  $p.html(html.replace(patterns.smile, emoticons.smile).
  replace(patterns.sad, emoticons.sad).
  replace(patterns.wink, emoticons.wink));  
 });
});
```

#### More Information

- [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Etmrs/)
- [JQuery: Inserting Emoticons](http://onwebdev.blogspot.com/2011/03/jquery-inserting-emoticons.html) (Source)